# Unable to read image from file Laravel-intervention

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.0, and I successfully installed intervention package for Laravel. I can do everything fine except this.

```
$img = Image::make(Input::file('companylogo'));
```

I get error

> Unable to read image from file ().

Comment: Are you certain the file exists?

Comment: yes it works fine with $img = Input::file('companylogo');

Comment: Is the file you are uploading actuly an image like an .jpg for example?

Comment: Yes it is. logo.jpg size 11,4 KB i checked limit it is 2048 KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Request::file('companyLogo'); 
 If still it is not working, then it may be the permission problem. Check for that and also cross-check the type of the file you are uploading.

Comment: I tried this and get ErrorException in ProfileController.php line 244: Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::file() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context